# Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js' - heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm a beginner using Heroku and I have a problem:
When I write `git push heroku master` in my terminal prompt, I'm getting an error:
`Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'`
I don't really know what I did wrong.
In the Procfile:
`web: node index.js`
In the package.json:

```
{
     "name": "the-chat",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "test": "node index.js",
       "start": "node index.js"
     },
     "keywords": [],
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
       "express": "^4.16.4",
       "grawlix": "^1.0.6",
       "jquery": "^3.3.1",
       "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
     }
   }
```

And the files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfDAQ.png
Anyone knows what's the problem? It would really help me, thanks!

Comment: Since its a javascript error, I would say its a problem inside your code. Also I would say the route should be specified from the root of the project, so it should start with `./` instead of `/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Tho, where should I replace / by ./ ?

Comment: I think you have `require('/app/index.js')` somewhere in your code. All imports should start with `./`. If not, Node will look for some installed package. If `app` is a folder in your project main directory, you should use `require('./app/index.js')` instead

Comment: no i dont have any require(/app/index.js)

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the error? Where does that come?

Comment: I fixed the bug, by restarting everything. I don't know what was the error.