# Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'

I have followed the suggestions on some previous [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391770/error-cannot-find-module-app-index-js-heroku) which didn't work out

Please take a look at my [Github Repo](https://github.com/chrismeeky/amona) and review my packgage.json and Procfile. I have been battling this issue for 2 hours

**Here is my package.json file**

```
{

  "name": "numberplatedetector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An app that links drivers and car owners",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false; export NODE_ENV=; NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false NODE_ENV=development npm install --only=dev --dev",
    "heroku-postbuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true; export NODE_ENV=production;",
    "coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "coveralls": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev-start": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "start": "node --require babel-polyfill ./build/index.js",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.15.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-mocked": "^1.4.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.6",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "sinon": "^7.4.1"
  }
}
```

**and here is the content of my Procfile:**

> web: node build/index.js